# Ubuntu RAID in UEFI system

Tags: raid, uefi

I tried to make Ubuntu RAID in UEFI system. I used 2x250 GB SATA HDD. The RAID is working properly. But i have some problem with the grub loader. Only the 1st HDD had boot loader. SO if I using only 2nd HDD, my computer doesn't boot. How to make both HDD bootable?

Comment: Are you using RAID 1 (mirroring) or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ubuntu's software RAID, the EFI System Partition (ESP) will not be part of the RAID configuration. To ensure bootability if a drive fails, you'll have to create ESPs on each of your hard disks and manually keep the contents of these drives synchronized. You may also need to create NVRAM entries for the boot loaders on each of these disks using the `efibootmgr` utility in Linux.